# Fourier series formula proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Is there any proof for this formula? $$f(x)=a_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big[a_{n}\cos\Big(\frac{n \pi x}{L}\Big)+b_{n}\sin\Big(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big)\Big]$$
It seems no matter how hard I look, this is just a given in any papers on the Fourier series.

Can anyone direct me to a proof of this formula or show how it is derived please.

Thank you.

Comment: Of course this is assumed in a _paper_ on Fourier analysis - the author assumes that the reader is familiar with the fundamentals of the subject! Look in an elementary _book_ on Fourier series. https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Fourier+series

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Defined $\sin$ and $\cos$ are orthonormal (each pair dot product should be zero). Hence, they can be the basis of the space.

Comment: What???? Basis for _what_ space? Any orthonormal set is a basis? No...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It is just a hint.